# Scandinavian characters åäö disappears in AJAX chat box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, utf-8, character-encoding

Chatbox jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // load messages every 1000 milliseconds from server.
    load_data = {'fetch':1};
    window.setInterval(function(){
     $.post('shout.php', load_data,  function(data) {
        $('.message_box').html(data);
        var scrolltoh = $('.message_box')[0].scrollHeight;
        $('.message_box').scrollTop(scrolltoh);
     });
    }, 1000);

    //method to trigger when user hits enter key
    $("#shout_message").keypress(function(evt) {
        if(evt.which == 13) {
                var iusername = $('#shout_username').val();
                var imessage = $('#shout_message').val();
                post_data = {'username':iusername, 'message':imessage};

                //send data to "shout.php" using jQuery $.post()
                $.post('shout.php', post_data, function(data) {

                    //append data into messagebox with jQuery fade effect!
                    $(data).hide().appendTo('.message_box').fadeIn();

                    //keep scrolled to bottom of chat!
                    var scrolltoh = $('.message_box')[0].scrollHeight;
                    $('.message_box').scrollTop(scrolltoh);

                    //reset value of message box
                    $('#shout_message').val('');

                }).fail(function(err) { 

                //alert HTTP server error
                alert(err.statusText); 
                });
            }
    });

    //toggle hide/show shout box
    $(".header").click(function (e) {
        //get CSS display state of .toggle_chat element
        var toggleState = $('.toggle_chat').css('display');

        //toggle show/hide chat box
        $('.toggle_chat').slideToggle();

        //use toggleState var to change close/open icon image
        if(toggleState == 'block')
        {
            $(".header div").attr('class', 'open_btn');
        }else{
            $(".header div").attr('class', 'close_btn');
        }


    });
});
```

If I write:
message:This will work but ö or ä doe's not

Console outputs this:

> (X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest)
>   message:This+will+work+but+%C3%A5+or+%C3%A4+doe's+not

How can I change Scandinavian characters to match html alternatives e.g & ouml; for ö in a chatbox after user send message (I don't want user to see transformation in input box)?


Or maybe is there some simple way to convert those %C3%A5 formatted "characters" in my php script?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where is your bug exactly, but the console output looks like it is uri-encouded. So you can try encoding and decoding messages before you send and after you recieve them, like this:

JS:

```
var encodedMessage = encodeURI(message); // takes "ö" and gives "%C3%B6"

var message = decodeURI(encodedMessage); // takes "%C3%B6" and gives "ö"
```

PHP (if needed): [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

Comment: https://www.sanwebe.com/assets/chat-shout-box/

This is same script that I use and it dosen't work either correctly...

Comment: @sukkis so have you tried the methods I've suggested? Try `imessage = encodeURI($('#shout_message').val())` and decode back the message in your `data`/`post_data` objects before posting.

Comment: Actually problem was in my php code.

If anyone uses same script and is having same problem here is the answer.....

`$message = filter_var(trim($_POST["message"])`drop after this-> `,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);`